# Java Servlet File Upload of images - is the code efficient or allowing for memory leak?

Tags: java, memory, servlets, image-processing, file-upload

My servlet does the following for a file submitted for upload through my JSP page.

**Step 1** - get the file, its always an image

**Step 2** - check if it needs to be resized

**Step 2a** - if needs resize, do it

**Step 3** - also resize and create thumbnail size 

**Step 4** - store new resized image in folder on server

**Step 5** - store thumbnail image in folder on server

The largest image size (per my client's request) the servlet will accept for processing is a 3900 x 3900...I know, that is huge! But that's what the client wants.

I've put the servlet up on my tomcat on my vps for testing and I'm seeing some pretty serious memory consumption.

**VPS Memory Limits**

I get 316MB of memory. With a fresh restart on Tomcat, memory is at about 108MB. The VPS is also running Apache server. 

**Apache**, with Tomcat STOPPED is using 45MB, so Tomcat is taking up 63MB on initial startup.

**Tomcat.conf** - file is has the following set for the heap.

```
# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=100

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=128
```

Once I run the image upload process - submitting an image file through a form on a JSP page - the servlet takes over from there doing the Steps I described above.

I use the same image to test things out. The image is sized at 3872 x 2592 pixels and it equates to 2.53MB.

I submit this image about 5 times. Each upload takes up to a minute, or more to complete.

### The Test Results

1 image : memory=150mb

2 image : memory = 179mb

3 image : 179.8

4 image: 188.8

5 image: 189.3

**Why such a jump after uploading an image that is only 2.53MB?**
I don't get it.  When the memory drops, it drops slightly. I uploaded another image after the first 5, and the memory went to 188.8.

**Is there something inefficient about my code?** I made sure to close all the streams, or at least I'm pretty sure I did.

**Any input is greatly appreciated.**

### My Image Upload and Resizing Servlet

```
public void addPhoto(Statement stmt, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpSession session) {

            BufferedInputStream bis = null; 
            BufferedImage bufimg = null;
            BufferedImage resized = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

            String ImageMain = "";
            String ImageThumb = "";                

            String dbShortPathMain = "images/gallery/";             
            String dbShortPathThumb = "images/gallery/";                


       String fileNameToLowerCase = "";
       String fileExtension = "";

       byte[] newimage = null;   

       boolean isPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);

       if(isPart) {


         FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

         ServletFileUpload fileupload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

         java.util.List items = fileupload.parseRequest(req);

         Iterator it = items.iterator();

         while(it.hasNext()) { //while1                                

                FileItem item = (FileItem)it.next();    
                String fieldValue = item.getName(); 

                if(!item.isFormField()) {

                    String fieldName = item.getFieldName();                                             

                    if(fieldName.equals("ImageMain")) { //10

                          //--------------------------
                          //continue processing upload
                          //field wasn't blank
                          //---------------------------
                          // Create a FileItem object to access the file.
                          File f = new File(fieldValue); 

                          // Get content type by filename.
                          String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(f.getName());                                  
                            if(contentType == null) contentType = "none";

                    if(!contentType.startsWith("image")) {
                       appendToURL += "&notfile=y";                             
                      } else {
                          //check size                          
                            bis = new BufferedInputStream(item.getInputStream());                       

                            //BufferedImage
                            bufimg = ImageIO.read(bis);                                         

                            //check size of image 
                            int img_width = bufimg.getWidth();
                            int img_height = bufimg.getHeight();

                            //not accepting images larger than 3900 x 3900
                            if(img_width > 3900 || img_height > 3900) { 
                               appendToURL += "&filesize=y";                                
                             } else {                            

                              //------------------------------------------
                              //  R E S I Z E  &   U P L O A D   F I L E 
                              //------------------------------------------
                                //#### STEP 1 - make size (600 max width) image #### 
                                double scale = (double)maxLargeImageSize/(double)img_width;                             

                                Image sized = getScaledInstanceAWT(bufimg, scale, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                                //convert image to BufferedImage
                                resized = toBufferedImage(sized, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);                                   

                                bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();       

                                //make file name characters all lowercase, and extract extension (.jpg)
                                fileNameToLowerCase = fieldValue.toLowerCase();                     
                                fileExtension = fileNameToLowerCase.substring(fileNameToLowerCase.indexOf(".")+1,fileNameToLowerCase.length());

                                //initialize buffer output stream for efficiency                 
                                //BufferedOutputStream
                                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(bytestream);

                                //W R I T E image to BufferedOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream
                                if(fileExtension.equals("png")) 
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"png",bos);                             

                                if(fileExtension.equals("jpg"))             
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"jpg",bos);                             

                                if(fileExtension.equals("jpeg"))                
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"jpeg",bos);                            

                                if(fileExtension.equals("gif"))
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"gif",bos);        

                                if(fileExtension.equals("bmp"))
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"bmp",bos);                                   

                                // Flush ByteArrayOutputStream                              
                                bytestream.flush();         

                                //convert the bytes in stream to byte array
                                //byte[]
                                newimage = bytestream.toByteArray();                                                                            

                                //specify the file name

                                ImageMain = FileUploadPath+"/thenewfile."+fileExtension;
                                dbShortPathMain += cat+"/thenewfile."+fileExtension;

                                fos = new FileOutputStream(ImageMain);              

                                fos.write(newimage);

                                fos.flush();                                    

                                //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                                //#### STEP 2 - make Thumb size (140 max width) image ####
                                scale = (double)maxThumbImageSize/(double)img_height;                               

                                sized = getScaledInstanceAWT(bufimg, scale, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                                //convert image to BufferedImage
                                resized = toBufferedImage(sized, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                                //used to convert the new image to bytes so it can be put into db
                                //ByteArrayOutputStream
                                bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                       

                                //initialize buffer output stream for efficiency                 
                                //BufferedOutputStream
                                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(bytestream);

                                //W R I T E image to BufferedOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream
                                if(fileExtension.equals("png")) 
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"png",bos);                             

                                if(fileExtension.equals("jpg"))             
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"jpg",bos);                             

                                if(fileExtension.equals("jpeg"))                
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"jpeg",bos);                            

                                if(fileExtension.equals("gif"))
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"gif",bos);        

                                if(fileExtension.equals("bmp"))
                                   ImageIO.write(resized,"bmp",bos);                                   

                                // Flush ByteArrayOutputStream                              
                                bytestream.flush();         

                                //convert the bytes in stream to byte array
                                //byte[]
                                newimage = bytestream.toByteArray();                                                                            

                                //specify the file name
                                ImageThumb = FileUploadPath+"/newfilethumb."+fileExtension;
                                dbShortPathThumb += cat+"/newfilethumb."+fileExtension;

                                fos = new FileOutputStream(ImageThumb);             

                                fos.write(newimage);

                                fos.flush();                                
                                //#### end large size ####  

                              //---------------------------------------

                        }

                        }                     


                      }                           

                  }//isFormField

                  }//while  

                }//isPart

    }//try
    catch(Exception e) {}

     finally {
    if (bis != null) try { bis.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (bytestream != null) try { bytestream.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (bos != null) try { bos.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (fos != null) try { fos.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }       

}//addPhoto


//-----------------------------------------------------------
//R E S I Z I N G   I M A G E   M E T H O D S
//-----------------------------------------------------------
        public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image image, int type) {
            BufferedImage result = null;
            try {
                    int w = image.getWidth(null);
                    int h = image.getHeight(null);
                    result = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
                    Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                    g.dispose();                    
                }//try
                catch(Exception e) {}

                return result;
        }//end

        public Image getScaledInstanceAWT(BufferedImage source, double scale, int hint) {        
            Image newimage = null;
            try {           
                    int w = (int) (source.getWidth() * scale);
                    int h = (int) (source.getHeight() * scale);        
                    newimage = source.getScaledInstance(w, h, hint);
                }//try
                catch(Exception e) {}               

                return newimage;
        }//end
```

Comment: Have you taken the time to verify the precision of your measures? How does your measures reflect the memory consumption of your code? Java takes more "OS memory" than it is actually using and this is depending on platform and JVM implementation. If you really want to see if your code is leaking memory, you should try to invoke your servlet over and over again and see if the memory footprint reaches an OutOfMemoryError or not.

Comment: I have tried to envoke the servlet many times. More than 25 times at least. What is your opinion of my code? Do you see any areas where I might be leaving objects open that won't be garbage collected?

Comment: You can do better than 25. http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Aside from making additional requests to the servlet - how's my code look?